# Can't change material icon weight in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm just trying to use the icon property (weight), I think this shouldn't be a problem, but it doesn't work, hope somebody knows how to use it properly

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6bLf.png)

Icons look like this: (I just wanna change the line width)

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zztP.png)

Thanks in advance! Hope is no rookie mistake haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently the font by default for icons doesn't support weight, so, unless you import a custom font for the icons it would not work, however there is a workaround for the custom font, you can do this:

```
Text(String.fromCharCode(Icons.space_dashboard_outlined.codePoint),
            style: TextStyle(
              inherit: false,
              fontSize: 50,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
              fontFamily: Icons.space_dashboard_outlined.fontFamily,
            ),
          )
```

For instance:

```
     Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Text(
            String.fromCharCode(Icons.space_dashboard_outlined.codePoint),
            style: TextStyle(
              inherit: false,
              fontSize: 50,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
              fontFamily: Icons.space_dashboard_outlined.fontFamily,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            String.fromCharCode(Icons.space_dashboard_outlined.codePoint),
            style: TextStyle(
              inherit: false,
              fontSize: 50,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontFamily: Icons.space_dashboard_outlined.fontFamily,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            String.fromCharCode(Icons.space_dashboard_outlined.codePoint),
            style: TextStyle(
              inherit: false,
              fontSize: 50,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
              fontFamily: Icons.space_dashboard_outlined.fontFamily,
            ),
          )
        ]),
```

woudl look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Flutter 3.10.0 material design 3 is implemented in Flutter so you can specify the weight of the icon easily like this:

```
Icon(Icons.star_outline,weight: 22)
```

Comment: I have enable material 3 or is it working with material 2 ? cause it didn't work for me

Comment: Does not reflect.